# unbundle with differents branches

Tags: git

I have to transfer a friend's git repository into my empty git repository. To do that he gives me a git bundle.

The problem is that the bundle has only one branch which is develop and my empty repo only has one branch which is master.

What is the best way to perform this ?

Comment: Why bother with the empty repository at all?

Comment: I must create the repository via a private similar tool of github.

Answer (score 1):

You should clone the bundle and start from there.

Create bare repo:

```
git clone --mirror PATH/TO/BUNDLE
```

Create private repo:

```
git clone PATH/TO/BUNDLE
```

Comment: What about an existing repo? AFAIU the command should be `git fetch PATH/TO/BUNDLE && git checkout develop`.

Comment: @phd You can pull or fetch updates from the bundle as you described. If you don't have anything setup on your side to start the clone is easier.